# Default DNS resolution behaviour, timeout and retry interval for Curl/LibCurl and the retry

Tags: curl, libcurl

I want to know the default DNS resolution behavior in Curl/LibCurl as compared to real browsers (like chrome), and how much does it depend on OS and the recursive resolver? 
- Also want to know if there are any retries like mentioned in manual page like 5 secs each, 2 retries?

- Is there a way on the machine to check or in the curl utility itself to check the DNS resolution timeout logic?
- Chrome keeps improving the logic to handle the DNS resolution. Is there a white paper on the recent ones?

Like in chrome it looks like it does 5 queries, 4 retries in ~ 9 seconds maintaining 300 ms interval up to 15 retries, as of now.

Answer (score 1):

First, to complicate matters, libcurl has several ways to do name resolving. Primarily, you can build libcurl to use different resolver backends - the default on most systems is the "threaded resolver" but there are also the "synchronous" stock resolver and the c-ares backend. Then, in recent libcurl versions you can also optionally make it use DNS-over-HTTPS to a specified server.

But focusing on the default method, the threaded one, it will fire up a helper thread when wanting to resolve a name and that thread will simply call `getaddrinfo()` and await the response. This function is generally provided by the libc/OS on the various platforms libcurl runs on and its behavior is also somewhat dictated by the [POSIX standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/freeaddrinfo.html) and it tends to be rather well worked out and polished code these days.

Chrome however, uses its own name resolving code on some platforms and the native (getaddrinfo) resolver functions on some (I've been told). Unfortunately, I lack the knowledge to say more about that...